# Vue.js bind object properties

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Why I can't bind the object properties in Vue? The object `addr` is not reactive immediately, but `test` is reactive, how come? In this case, how should I bind it?

HTML

```
<div id="app">

   <input type="text" id="contactNum" v-model="addr.contactNum" name="contactNum">

   <input type="text" id="test" v-model="test" name="test">
   <br/>
   {{addr}}<br/>
   {{addr.contactNum}}<br/>
   {{test}}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      addr: {},
      test: ""
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sam3/7wa0hu1f/)

Comment: Refer to the [change detection caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) section of VueJS docs. You are running into this issue because `addr` is reactive but `addr.contactNum` is not, since it is not declared when the component is mounted. There is no other way (due to limitations in JS itself) than to explicitly declare it, either when initializing the `data` object or using `Vue.set()`. Even though you may have arbitrary number of inputs, you will know which key they will be referring to in the `addr` object, so you can use that in `Vue.set()`.

Comment: An alternative way is actually to compose a generic input element, say `<my-input-component>` with its own `v-model` mapping, and you simply include them in your app as a component. These components can emit the updated values to the parent (app in this case), so the parent will always have the updated values of all inputs in itself.

Comment: by the way, in my enviroment it works just fine. i have copied the code to the generated project by `vue-cli`. i am also using vue 2.5.2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

During initialisation Vue sets up getters and setters for every known property. Since `contactNum` isn't initially set up, Vue doesn't know about that property and can not update it properly. This can be easly fixed by adding `contactNum` to your `addr` object.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    addr: {
      contactNum: "" // <-- this one
    },
    test: ""
  }
});
```

The above is called **[reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)** in Vue. Since Vue doesn't support adding properties dynamically to its reactivity system, we may need some kind of workaround. A possible [solution](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) is provided by the API. In case of dynamically added properties we can use `Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)`.

Doing so the markup would need to get some update. Instead of using `v-model` it'd be better to use an event listener like `@input`. In this case our markup could look like this.

```
<input type="text" id="contactNum" @input="update(addr, 'contactNum', $event)" name="contactNum">
```

So basically the function will get triggered every time the input elements value changes. Obviously doing so will also require some adjustments on the JS part.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    addr: {},
    test: ""
  },
  methods: {
    update: function(obj, prop, event) {
      Vue.set(obj, prop, event.target.value);
    }
  }
});
```

Since Vue triggers `Vue.set()` on any reactive element, we simply call it on our own because Vue doesn't recognizes a dynamically added property as a reactive one. Of course, this is only one possible solution and there may be lots of other workarounds. A fully working example can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ggaro5m0/1/).

Comment: oh no, got better way? I have a lot of property for `addr` object, I don't want to initialize them one by one.

Comment: You can assign addr itself with new object and it will be setup correctly.

Comment: @MatJ What do you mean assign a new object? Empty object?

Comment: YOU CAN TRY TO CREATE SEPARATE COMPONENT :)

Comment: You forgot to put '':value=addr.contactNum'' inside the input

Answer (score 11):

As per my comments, there are several things that you want to consider:

- The reason why your code is not working is due to the **inherent inability of JS to watch for changes in object properties**. This means that even though `addr` is reactive, any properties added to `addr` that is not done when it is declared will make it non-reactive. Refer to the VueJS docs for more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats
- If you are going to have an arbitrary number of input fields, you are probably better of **composing a custom input component**, and simply use `v-for` to iteratively inject input fields based on the number of input fields you have.

---

Now back to the second point, if you know what fields `addr` will have, you can simply declare it in your app. We create a new `updateFormData` method, which is called by the component:

```
data: {
  addrFields: ['contactNum', ...],
  addr: {},
  test: ""
},
methods: {
  updateFormData: function(id, value) {
    this.$set(this.addr, id, value);
  }
}
```

We can still store your form data in the `addr` object, which will be updated by the `updateFormData` method based on the received payload using [`.$set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). Now, we can then create a custom Vue component for your input element.

In the example below, the component will iterate through all your `addrFields`, and pass down the `addrField` as a prop using `:id="addrField"`. We also want to make sure that we capture the custom-named `updated` event emitted from within the component.

```
<my-input
     v-for="(addrField, i) in addrFields"
     :key="i"
     :id="addrField"
     v-on:inputUpdated="updateFormData"></my-input>
```

The template can look something like the following. It simply uses the `id` prop for both its `id`, `name`, and `placeholder` attribute (the latter for easy identification in the demo). We bind the `@change` and `@input` events, forcing it to trigger the `updated` callback:

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-input">
    <input
    type="text"
    :id="id"
    :name="id"
    :placeholder="id"
    @input="updated"
    @change="updated">
</script>
```

In the component logic, you let it know that it will receive `id` as a prop, and that it should emit an `inputUpdated` event using [`$.emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit). We attach the ID and value as payloads, so that we can inform the parent what has updated:

```
var myInput = Vue.component('my-input', {
    template: '#my-input',
  props: {
    id: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updated: function() {
        this.$emit('inputUpdated', this.id, this.$el.value);
    }
  }
});
```

---

With the code above, we have a working example. In this case, I have created an arbirary array of input fields: `contactNum`, `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```js
var myInput = Vue.component('my-input', {
    template: '#my-input',
  props: {
    id: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updated: function() {
        this.$emit('updated', this.id, this.$el.value);
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      addrFields: ['contactNum', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
      addr: {},
      test: ""
    },
    methods: {
        updateFormData: function(id, value) {
        this.$set(this.addr, id, value);
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   
   <my-input
     v-for="(addrField, i) in addrFields"
     :key="i"
     :id="addrField"
     v-on:updated="updateFormData"></my-input>
   
   <input type="text" id="test" v-model="test" name="test" placeholder="test">
   <br/>
   <strong>addr:</strong> {{addr}}<br/>
   <strong>addr.contactNum:</strong> {{addr.contactNum}}<br />
   <strong>test:</strong> {{test}}
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="my-input">
    <input
    type="text"
    :id="id"
    :name="id"
    :placeholder="id"
    @input="updated"
    @change="updated">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **Vue** `data` with this since it's getter and setter methods are not set up. Also, check out **Declarative Reactive Rendering** on Vue docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering):

```
data: {
    addr: {
      contactNum: "" // <-- this one
    },
    test: ""
  }
```

Comment: got better way? I have lot of properties, prefer not to initialize one by one.

Comment: Yes, you can set Vue properties with Vue.set outside vue scope.