# VueJS Array update bug

Tags: arrays, data-binding, vue.js

I have a JSFiddle below to explain my problem but basically I have an array called `tiles` which has a title. When the instance is `created()` I add a field to this array called `active`

I then output this array in an `<li>` element and loop through it outputting the `title` and `active` objects. My problem is as you can see in the fiddle when I run `v-on:click="tile.active = true"` nothing happens to the active state written in the `<li>` element

but if I run `v-on:click="tile.title = 'test'"` it seems to update the active object and the title object.

Its strange behaviour I can't seem to work out why. Does anyone have any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/jgb34dqo/

Thanks

Comment: Not looked at the example yet but you probably want this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js bind object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925527/vue-js-bind-object-properties)

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with Vue not knowing about your properties, change your array to this:

```
tiles: [
  {
    title: 'tile one',
    active: false
  },
  {
    title: 'tile two',
    active: false
  },
  {
    title: 'tile three',
    active: false
  }
]
```

This allows Vue to know about the active property and in turn it knows to monitor that variable.

It's worth looking at this [link about Vue Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) as it helps with understanding how and when data will change automagically.

### If you **must** add the properties after

take a look at [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set). It allows you to add props to an object that then get watched by vue. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgb34dqo/3/), notice the change:

```
this.tiles.forEach(function(tile) {
  // Tell vue to add and monitor an `active` prop against the tile object
  this.$set(tile, 'active',  false);
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: I understand that my question is how do I make it understand my properties? I am pulling data from an API which doesn't have an active object so I have added this manually.

Comment: Ok, I understand, give me a moment, I'll fiddle an example for you.

Comment: Edit: Just fixed the fiddle link.