# How v-model make a property of object reactive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

Link to my project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v-model-3j96f

As of my link above, the is a file named HelloWorld.vue inside the "components" folder:
`inputvalue.bbbb` is a reactive data which is defined in data option, but

It's weird that `inputvalue.cccc` will become reactive after input with the v-model, but `inputvalue.cccc` will not reactive with `@input`.

In this question ([Vue.js bind object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925527/vue-js-bind-object-properties)), the first situation should not be possible.

Comment: please explain your problem properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `v-model` will automatically use `$set` to set the values on nested properties. This ensures this it works with array indices, as well as working for object properties that don't exist, as per your example.

If you're unfamiliar with `$set` it is documented here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

The code for this part of `v-model` in Vue is here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/399b53661b167e678e1c740ce788ff6699096734/src/compiler/directives/model.js#L44

In your example there are two inputs that use `cccc`. As you noticed, if you edit the input that uses `v-model` then everything works fine. However, if you use the `:value`/`@input` input first then it doesn't work, even if you subsequently use the `v-model` input. The behaviour is, somewhat oddly, determined by which of those two inputs you edit first.

The reason for that can be seen in the code for `$set`:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/399b53661b167e678e1c740ce788ff6699096734/src/core/observer/index.js#L212

The problem is that `$set` will only add a reactive property if the property doesn't already exist. So if you use the `:value`/`@input` input first it will create a non-reactive `cccc` property and once that is created it can't be made reactive, even if you use `$set`. It would have to be removed using `delete` before it could be re-added reactively.

Comment: But...how do you intercept the $set call?