# Vue.js bind object field with object property decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-property-decorator

I want to bind the field of an object using the [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator). The following code should illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="this.box.description" placeholder="The description for the box"></textarea>
</template>

<script lang="tsx">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class BoxScreen extends Vue {
  @Prop() private box!: Box;

  public created() {
    // init box with an Axios request
  }
}
</script>
```

The description within the `textarea` gets properly initialized, but the binding doesn't seem to work once I start editing the text. I need the same solution as for this question, but working with `vue-property-decorator`: [Vue.js bind object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925527/vue-js-bind-object-properties).

Comment: Try with `PropSync`

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Does `box` really need to be a public prop (set by a parent component)? It looks like you just initialize it within the component, so it could probably be private. If that's the case, you could just use a normal class field, and your `v-model` would work as you expected in your example.

Comment: https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#PropSync was saying to use this  property as it similar to computed one which results in reactive state

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you're trying to mutate a prop. Try the following instead:

```
<template>
  <textarea
    v-model="description"
    placeholder="The description for the box"
  ></textarea>
</template>

<script lang="tsx">
import { Component, Prop, Watch, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

export default class BoxScreen extends Vue {
  @Prop() private box!: Box;

  description: string;

  @Watch('box.description', { immediate: true })
  onChangeBoxDescription(): void {
    this.description = this.box.description;
  }

  public created() {
    // init box with an Axios request
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to make sure that `this.box.description` is always in sync with the textarea. It seems with your solution the textarea will be updated when the box description changes, but not the other way around.